# Mapping typescript types

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

I am trying add types to a function, that takes as parameters an array of typed objects, and return a mapped array of another type :

```
const createAnimals = <T extends AnimalFactory<any>[]>(factories: T) => {
  return factories.map((f) => f());
};
```

Once this function is properly typed, it should throw an error with the following code :

```
const factories = [() => new Dog(), () => new Cat()];
const animals = createAnimals(factories);

// ❌ should fail !
animals[0].meow();
```

I would like the compiler to know that `animals` is of type `[Dog, Cat]` .

I have been trying to use `infer`, but without success so far.

Comment: What do your attempts look like? What is `AnimalFactory`? A type you already have? Or something you tried to use to make this work?

Comment: Why do you want to use generics for this? It doesn't immediately seem necessary.

Comment: thanks for your feedback @T.J.Crowder . I will edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to do this, but the solution will require you to type `factories` as read-only, or the type will simply not contain enough information.

```
const factories = [() => new Dog(), () => new Cat()] as const;
```

If you declare a type for such factories (which aren't really about animals anymore, but let's stick with it)

```
type AnimalFactory<T> = () => T
```

you can create a mapped type that takes a tuple of `AnimalFactory`'s and yields a tuple of the respective animal types:

```
type FactoryAnimals<T extends AnimalFactory<unknown>[]> =
  {[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends AnimalFactory<infer A> ? A : never}
```

Now you can use `AnimalFactory` for the return type of `createAnimals`:

```
const createAnimals = <T extends AnimalFactory<unknown>[]>
  (factories: readonly [...T]) => factories.map(f => f()) as FactoryAnimals<T>;
```

Unfortunately the `as FactoryAnimals<T>` assertion is necessary since TypeScript can't infer that doing a map on the tuple yields the mapped type. The `readonly [...T]` bit is to avoid having a read-only `T`, which would cause a read-only return type and require an extra assertion.

If you call `createAnimals` on the factories it produces a tuple of the desired type:

```
const animals = createAnimals(factories);
// type: [Dog, Cat]

// ❌ should fail !
animals[0].meow(); // Error: Property 'meow' does not exist on type 'Dog'.
```

And if you call it with an explicit array instead of a variable, you can leave out the `as const`, since the `[...T]` type causes `factories` to be considered a tuple:

```
const animals = createAnimals([() => new Dog(), () => new Cat()]);
// type: [Dog, Cat]
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=59&pln=20&pc=79#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)

Comment: I was *so close* when I had to pack it in for the night. Just as well that I did, though, because I don't think I'd've got the `factories: readonly [...T]` part. Very cool!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you! (and also thanks for creating the animals, I gave them a second life on my playground :-)

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation :) Still, I am surprised on how complex it has to be ! Mixing all the `as const`, `factories: readonly [...T]`, and `{[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends AnimalFactory<infer A> ? A : never}`